# Notation Confusion (Specifically: "Such That", & Multiple $\exists$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, regular-language

There are a couple of notation-related matters that I find myself clumsily working around quite often when writing proofs, and I was hoping for some help with dealing with them:

Let's say that $L$, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular languages.
I claim:
$w \in (L_1 \cup L_2) \cdot L \iff \exists w_1 \in (L_1 \cup L_2), w_2 \in L$ such that $w=w_1\cdot w_2$.
So I have two questions about this:

1. How should I handle that "there exist *several* $w_i$ such that..."? That is to say: is it okay to separate them with a comma as I did ($\exists w_1 \in ..., w_2 \in ...$), or would it be better to add a new $\exists$ per $w_i$ (e.g. $\exists w_1 \in ... \wedge \exists w_2 \in ...$)?
2. Is there any kind of standard notation to use as a substitute for "such that"? I gather that $|$ and $:$ are used in set-builder notation and not in cases such as this one; so it'd be *off* to write something like: "$w \in (L_1 \cup L_2) \cdot L \iff \exists w_1 \in (L_1 \cup L_2), w_2 \in L: w=w_1\cdot w_2$". Is that correct?
   Looking at some questions & answers on SE and on Google, my understanding was that the common consensus seems to be that writing "such that" is the preferred method, usually, but my native language is written RTL, and that makes it a bit awkward sometimes when I want to add "such that" in the middle of a LTR mathematical statement (I usually find myself adding line breaks in unfortunate places to deal with it), so I was hoping for some clear, creative solution based on standard notation for this.
3. Does it look okay if I write something like: "$\exists w_1, w_2$ such that $w_1\in ... \wedge w_2 \in ... \wedge w = w_1 \cdot w_2$"? That is, to concentrate all the "exists" in one place, and all their "descriptions" in another?

I get a strong sense that I'm overthinking it all, but I dislike the way a lot of my notation usages feel so clumsy to me. If you can see some sort of root cause (maybe a mindset issue or something more general like that) for my confusion & are able to point it out, that'd be great, too.

Comment: For point 1: Why not $\forall i \exists w_i \in $ ?

Comment: There are several... is $\exists w_i \exists w_j$. If they **must** be different: $\exists w_i \exists w_j (w_i \ne w_j)$

Comment: "such that" is absorbed by the standard syntax $\exists x Px$ reads: "there is some $x$ such that $P$ holds of it"

Comment: @SagarM: I see now that my phrasing there wasn't great; but what I meant is that there are multiple $w$s, each with its own "description" (for instance, one is in $L_1 \cup L_2$ and one is in $L$), so what's on the right side of $\exists$ will change between the two (and not in a manner than can be directly described with a simple change of index).

Comment: Thanks for the note about $\exists x P x$, @MauroALLEGRANZA! That does help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d write your example as

$$w \in (L_1\cup L_2)\cdot L \iff \exists w_1 \in (L_1\cup L_2): \exists w_2 \in L: w_1\cdot w_2 = w$$

The “such that “ is implicit in the final “:” (after the quqtifiers, before the term) for me, it need not be written out in natural language, and I prefer to give each variable it’s own quantifier, though other texts will do it differently. It depends also on how strictly “first order logic” you want to be, some will even not like the bounded quantifers and replace a statement like $\exists x \in A:P(x)$ by $\exists x: (x \in A) \land P(x)$ as well.

Like I said, it’s a matter of taste, largely. Just make sure it’s understandable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! That does make it feel like I've been overthinking it a bit. Seems like it's pretty flexible as long as the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely insist on using symbols, I would write

$$w\in(L_1\cup L_2)\cdot L\leftrightarrow\exists w_1\in L_1\cup L_2\,\exists w_2\in L(w=w_1\cdot w_2)\,.$$

But if I were actually doing it myself, I’d use intelligible English:

> $w\in(L_1\cup L_2)\cdot L$ iff there are $w_1\in L_1\cup L_2$ and $w_2\in L$ such that $w=w_1\cdot w_2$.

Or on occasion even:

> A word $w$ is in $(L_1\cup L_2)\cdot L$ if and only if there are words $w_1\in L_1\cup L_2$ and $w_2\in L$ such that $w=w_1\cdot w_2$.

Comment: The main reason I want to be able to use symbols on occasion is that I sometimes write my proofs in a RTL language, as I mentioned, at which point it gets pretty awkward to mix mathematical LTR writing with RTL descriptions, but I definitely agree that your example drives home the point that intelligible English works a lot better than an almost forceful use of symbols; I'll definitely shoot for that, when possible. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ShyGuy: You’re welcome.